# Get DN of logger in user in Active Directory

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap, python-ldap

I am using python-ldap library to connect to LDAP (Active Directory) and read & write users' data.

I am looking for a way to get DN of a logged in user. There is `ldap.whoami_s()` operation, but AD returns me something such as `u:MAIL\johnny`, which isn't really a DN.

Is it possible to get a proper DN somehow? Is the returned value `u:MAIL\johnny` linked to an attribute in AD that I could at least search for? I would prefer the solution to be independent of AD configuration if possible.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. The distinguished name is always returned in a search request for each matched entry.

Comment: I believe you are referring to the 2nd part. You're right, but I don't know how to search for DN basing on this `u:MAIL\johnny` - what is the meaning of this string?

Comment: The `u:` appears to be an `authZid`, which is one of two choices used for a BIND request, the other being a distinguished name. This is AD to which you refer, and I don't know much about that system. If it were a compliant LDAP server, one would use either `u:` to BIND with a SASL BIND or a DN with a simple BIND request. You'd better get help from someone who understands AD better than me, I'm an LDAP guy, not an AD guy. RFC2422 for SASL and RFC4513 for BIND requests.